# cuda-gdb can't see available devices

Tags: cuda, cuda-gdb

I'm trying to use cuda-gdb debug my code on a remote cluster via ssh. There're 6 Tesla C2070 gpu on the node:

```
$ deviceQuery | grep "^Device"
Device 0: "Tesla C2070"
Device 1: "Tesla C2070"
Device 2: "Tesla C2070"
Device 3: "Tesla C2070"
Device 4: "Tesla C2070"
Device 5: "Tesla C2070"
```

But when I run code under cuda-gdb, it still gives me error code=24: 
"fatal:  All CUDA devices are used for display and cannot be used while debugging. "

I've already set `-gencode arch=compute_20,code=sm_20` and compiles well. When I type `info cuda devices` in the debugger, it spits `No CUDA devices`. I also tried export `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES="0,2"` but still not working. What should I do?
I'm using cuda 5.0. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is X running on the remote cluster node?

Comment: I'm not sure: $ ps -e |grep X, the result is 00:00:16 Xorg. But shouldn't that just decrease the visible gpu by 1?

Comment: It depends on how the `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` file is set up.   An X server can be configured to start up on all of the GPUs.

Comment: Oh, thanks. Then I guess I have to contact the administrator.

Comment: You might try successively `export CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES="0"` then `...="1"` then `...="2"` etc. but very likely if more than one of the GPUs have X running then probably they all do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running "lsof /dev/nvidia*", it will show you which program is holding the device nodes open. If X is using those GPUs, it will be evident from the output.